# Sorting a list of data's in json format

Tags: json, linux, sorting

So I am trying to sort through a good few lines of text and numbers in JSON format. An example of some of these lines would be

```
{ "a": "123456", "b": 16, "c": "Data" }
{ "a": "654321", "b": 30, "c": "Data" }
{ "a": "015864", "b": 18, "c": "Data" }
```

I am trying to sort these in a way that the value for B (16, 30, and 18, respectively) is sorted from largest to lowest. Example:

```
{ "a": "654321", "b": 30, "c": "Data" }
{ "a": "015864", "b": 18, "c": "Data" }
{ "a": "123456", "b": 16, "c": "Data" }
```

I know it is possible, but I have 0 idea how regex works, or if there is something else I could use. Preferably able to be done from a linux command line, but if it needs to be done with notepad++ or something I can make it work. Also please explain why your suggestion works so I can learn, not just copy-paste your suggestion. Thank you!!

Edit: I was informed Regex would not work. I am okay with any scripting language being used, as long as I can learn how to do these things myself. Python, Perl, php, any of them work.

Comment: Having those objects in the same file makes for invalid JSON.

Comment: Regex cannot count nor do arithmetic comparisons. You need to indicate a preferred scripting language whether its Perl, Python, PHP, or something else.

Comment: I know it is invalid json, but for some reason an application I was using listed like 3,000 of them into a single file... I am trying to sort these so I can figure out which ones I actually needed lol.

Comment: Okay, well my comments still apply. You need actual scripting/programming, regex alone cannot help you.

Comment: I see okay. I'll add that I do not mind which scripting language is used, and that I was informed regex can not do what I need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the fields are aligned you can sort as if it's a text file.

```
$ sort -k5,5nr file

{ "a": "654321", "b": 30, "c": "Data" }
{ "a": "015864", "b": 18, "c": "Data" }
{ "a": "123456", "b": 16, "c": "Data" }
```

field are space delimited, sorting based on field 5 values (which are `b` values), numerical reverse sort.

Comment: can you explain the `-k5,5nr` part in the expression?

Comment: That works just fine! Thank you! solved my issue.